# Run Task Immediately Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, codeplex

I'm using [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper from Codeplex](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com)  and I need to fire task as soon as possible and only once. I don't found any API that could execute created task immediately (I can be wrong). So how can I create a trigger that fires only once and as soon as possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found solution [here](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/discussions/260927).

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
   string task = "TaskName";
   // This will find it even if its down in a folder. Alternately you could call:
   // Task t = ts.GetTask(task);
   Task t = ts.FindTask(task);
   if (t != null)
      t.Run();
}
```